# Adding link to post thumbnail

Tags: php, wordpress, post, thumbnails

```
<div id="page" class="hfeed site">

<?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() && ! post_password_required() ) : ?>


    <?php the_post_thumbnail('full');

    else: ?>



    <div id="headimg"><img class="ImageResize560" src="<?php header_image(); ?>"></div>
```

I need to use this code, so that I can link the image, same time

```
<?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) : ?>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">
        <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
    </a>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Basically I need to link the post thumbnail to homepage... I tried but I get error.. somewhere wrong with "else: ?>"

Comment: Looks like you're not closing out your `else` in the first code block. Try adding `<?php endif; ?>` just below your `<div id="heading"`.

Comment: I tried not working

Comment: What is your error? You say you get an error. Is it an error message? If so update your question details with the error message

Comment: Yes. I get (https://www.dropbox.com/s/ox11aodkrsbavfw/Screenshot%20at%20Jul%2006%2013-24-38.png?dl=0) markup error

Comment: thats different than the code you posted. Look within the `a` tag attribute for the `href`. You aren't closing the `<?php` brackets. Right before the closing `"` add `?>`

Comment: Like this `<a href="<?php the_post_thumbnail('full'); ?>">`. Also I should mention that `the_post_thumbnail` echoes html not a permalink. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_post_thumbnail/

Comment: I tried, since next line has  'else: ?>'  if I close, then else if is ignored..

Comment: Because you have to open the brackets again like this `<?php else : ?>`

Comment: yes, start working now

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code

```
<div id="page" class="hfeed site">

<?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() && ! post_password_required() ) : ?>


<?php $image_url = home_url( ); ?>

    <a href="<?php echo $image_url; ?>">

    <?php the_post_thumbnail('full'); ?>

    </a>

    <?php else : ?>



    <div id="headimg"><img class="ImageResize560" src="<?php header_image(); ?>"></div>
```